# Laravel submit data to controller and then send the data to action URL

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

```
<form id="myForm" name="theForm" action="https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>MERCHANT_ACC_NO</td>
<td><input name="MERCHANT_ACC_NO" id="MERCHANT_ACC_NO" type="text" value="abc"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AMOUNT</td>
<td><input name="AMOUNT" id="AMOUNT" type="number" value="123"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" id='submit_payment' value="Make Payment">
</form>
```

- If I click the submit button here, I will able to submit data to the action URL, but how can I first submit this data to Laravel controller, and then in controller send the data to the action URL(https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp)?

Comment: Create a route/controller/method to send to, process the data, use [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client) to resend it to the payment url

Comment: Tq, brombeer, this look working.

Comment: But I got one problem when using HTTP client when I return $response, its redirect to my website URL rather than URL(https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp).

Comment: Hard to tell without any code. Not sure what you mean with "_its redirect to my website URL rather than URL_", the HTTP client should make a request to that URL https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp

Comment: Like this:
`$request = Http::asForm()->post('https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp', [''MERCHANT_ACC_NO'=> 'asd', 'AMOUNT'=>'123'']
return $request;`
This return will go to URL(https://mywebsite/PaymentWindow.jsp) rather than (https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp).
Sry for the poor explanation :(

Comment: `[''MERCHANT_ACC_NO'=> 'asd', 'AMOUNT'=>'123'']` has too many quotes, should be `['MERCHANT_ACC_NO'=> 'asd', 'AMOUNT'=>'123']`. Yes, because `/bank/` is not a valid domain to go to, that should be `bank.com` or something, don't know which payment-provider you're using, but I guess they have documentation somewhere

Comment: @brombeer Tq for answering my question, I think it might be the return problem.
Hmm, is it possible to post the data to URL (https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp) and load the page URL (https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp) at the same time?

Comment: Again: `https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp` is not a valid URL, what is this? Why do you keep using it? Do you have a RewriteRule/alias set up somewhere that makes this a valid URL? Do you have access to `PaymentWindow.jsp`? Good luck solving this

Comment: @brombeer Sry to make you misunderstood, the URL `https://bank/PaymentWindow.jsp` is just a sample URL, I got a proper URL that able to access(just I didn't show it here) and able to use the HTTP client that you teach me to post the data to the bank URL, is just that it won't redirect me to payment window page to let me fill in credit card information. The data is post successful using the HTTP client. Anyway, thank you for the help :)